Mac Console syslogd[360]: ASL Sender Statistics - logging messages
I looked on the Mac Console app's system.log to determine the cause of network disconnection events, and saw these "ASL Sender Statistics".  A Reddit post (https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/1ds4c9z/asl_sender_statistics) suggests it's just a generic message, and @bmike clarified to me the number (in this case 360) is just the process ID of the syslog daemon itself.  Given various posts about this including on Apple's Forum etc, can someone definitively say there is no info to be garnered from these log messages, or if there is, where can one find it?

ASL isn’t related to network events at all. Why not ask the question more openly (how can I diagnose network disconnects) instead of focusing on a specific log entry? That would allow people to either point out existing documentation or create new one by providing detailed answers.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is likely to be closed without a clear and stand alone question that people can answer. I’ll try to help with an explanation of what that message is: likely irrelevant noise compared to whatever problem you face.

Console messages are generally not for us and you need code level access to decipher them. There are exceptions, and sometimes a message is very helpful, but that isn’t this message.
The meaning of ASL Sender Statistics is that a periodic process was triggered to generate statistics from the era of Apple System Logging.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging


This is a pretty good response.  I was surprsised though by the resistance to addressing what system.log messages mean (as part of ULS, ASL or Syslogd).  This is an important application in itself, and ironically your response will clear up other questions (such as on Apple's Forum), even if this message isn't helpful.  What I found in the end is the log command on terminal is more helpful for understanding what the MacOS is doing.  But thanks again.
